# Proving that the function is differentiable and $f'(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Consider a function $f (x) $ such that $f (x)=\begin {cases} x^2 &
 \text {x=irrational}     \\ 0   &\text {x=rational} \end {cases}$
Then prove that $f $ is differentiable  at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ $$\text {Attempt} $$ .                  . 
Now I consider two sequences $x_n=\frac {\sqrt{2}}{n},y_n=\frac {1}{n} $ one irrational one rational both going to $0$ as $n\to \infty $. But now the problem is how to consider LHD,RHD.Do we have to consider irrational case then rational case and if both limits go to same value then say that function is differentiable.I can easily see the graph on graphical calculator and verify the result but I am more interested in analytical method.

Comment: I can't see this function being continuous anywhere but $x = 0$.

Comment: Differentiability will not be proven by choosing some specific sequences.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is not differentiable on all of its domain. It is only differentiable at $x=0$. Elsewhere it is not even continuous.

Note that we have $$0 \leq \left|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}\right| \leq |x|$$

Taking $x \to 0$ proves the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ ($\ne0$) is rational,

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0$$

and when irrational,

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{x^2-0}{x-0}=x.$$

Both tend to $0$ so *yes*.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\leq\left\vert \dfrac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \right\vert=\left\vert \dfrac{f(x)}{x}\right\vert \leq \dfrac {x^2} {|x|}=|x| \underset{x\to 0}\to0$$

Hence $f'(0)=0$.

Note that taking two different sequences converging to one point is not enough to prove that a function is differentiable at that point, or even that it is continuous. You have to consider all sequences. Here you can prove the result without considering sequences.